# Add ssh passphrase when pushing from local machine to remote server via git

Tags: git, ssh

I am trying to push from my local machine to remote server via

```
git push production master
```

but i am getting the error

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

And i think its cos i need to add the passphrase to the ssh command. Because when login in to my server via ssh i have to enter the passphrase each time via this prompt.

```
Authenticating with public key "************"
Passphrase for key "*************":
```

I can ssh to the server normally but i have to supply a passphrase cos that's how i set it up and i cannot push to the repository as explained above.

How do i add the passphrase when adding the remote server to my remote's if that is the right thing to do?

Comment: Try adding your key to the `ssh-agent` through something like
`ssh-add -KA ~/.ssh/id_rsa` then verifying with `ssh-add -L`.

Comment: thanks...will try that and let you know how it goes